# I need to execute a C program from a PHP script

Tags: php, c++, c, exec

Ok i wanted to create a crawler with my PHP script. Certain parts of my crawler requires real fast manipulation of strings thats why i have decided to use a C/C++ program to assist my PHP script for that particular job. The following is my code:

```
$op=exec('main $a $b');
echo $op;
```

main is the executable file generated using my C file `main.c` i.e `main.exe`. in the above operation i just made a simple C program which accepts 2 values from PHP and returns the sum of the two values. the following is how my C program in looking like

```
#include< stdio.h >
#include< stdlib.h >
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i=add(atoi(argv[1]),atoi(argv[2]));
  printf("%d\n",i);
  return 0;
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
  int c;
  c=a+b;
  return c;
}
```

i tried to execute the program via the CMD `main 1 1` and it returned `2`....it worked! when i entered them in the php script like this,

```
$a=1;
$b=1;
$op=exec('main $a $b');
echo $op;
```

it didn't work as expected so any ideas, suggestions or anything else i need to do on my code. I would be great if you could show me an example. THANKS IN ADVANCE!!!

Comment: You need to review the [strings part of the manual](http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) an dunderstand the differences between single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: I hope you do realise string standard PHP functions for string manipulation are C++. I've seen this mistake made before, by people who benchmarked an executable vs a PHP function, instead of benchmarking the PHP+exec+executable VS PHP.

Answer (score 3):

You should enclosed the arguments of `exec` with double quotes since you're passing variables. And the output of your program is in the second argument of `exec`.

```
exec("main $a $b", $out);
print_r($out);
```

See [`exec()` reference](http://php.net/exec).

Answer (score 2):

The function `atoi()` cannot distinguish invalid and valid inputs.
I suggest you use `strtol()` instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void quit(const char *msg) {
  if (msg) fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int add(int, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int a, b, i;
  char *err;

  if (argc != 3) quit("wrong parameter count");
  a = strtol(argv[1], &err, 10);
  if (*err) quit("invalid first argument");
  b = strtol(argv[2], &err, 10);
  if (*err) quit("invalid second argument");

  i = add(a, b);
  printf("%d\n", i);
  return 0;
}

int add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Comment: No. It has to do with his quotes.

Comment: Of course it has to do with his quotes, which is trivial (and, frankly speaking, can be solved just with comment). But this answer deals with more subtle error, hence +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an executable ./main.
And then use this code.It works

```
<?php
 $a=1;
 $b=1;
 echo exec("./main $a $b"); 
?>
```